# Clojure doto macro

Tags: java, clojure

I am going to call the `.toUpperCase` method within a `doto` macro like follows but the doto returns the small letters:

```
(doto (java.lang.String. "clojure")
       (.toUpperCase))
```

returns "clojure". I do the macroexpansion and as the return value is the object created:
`(clojure.core/let [G__7359 (java.lang.String. "cojure")] (.toUpperCase     G__7359) G__7359)`
, but why i don't get the uppercased answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`doto` is part of Clojure's Java interop features. It is designed to make it possible to write java with out soooo darn many parens. so

```
Foo foo = new Foo;
foo.setX().setY().makeFactory().applyPhaseOfMoon();
```

which has 8 parens becomes:

```
(doto foo .setY .makeFactory .applyPhaseOfMoon)
```

which has a total of two.

In this case if we dig into the expanstion of your example:

```
user> (doto "hi" .toUpperCase)
"hi"
```

expands to:

```
user> (macroexpand-1 '(doto "hi" .toUpperCase))
(clojure.core/let [G__110453 "hi"]
   (.toUpperCase G__110453) 
   G__110453)
```

where the second line does this:

```
user> (.toUpperCase "hi")
"HI"
```

and then **throws the answer away and returns the saved value** form the start. I personally never see `doto` used in practice outside of places where people are translating java to clojure inorder to call some API.

Answer (score 8):

From the [documentation](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doto):

> Evaluates x then calls all of the methods and functions with the value
>   of x supplied at the front of the given arguments.  The forms are
>   evaluated in order. **Returns x.**

`doto` returns the original argument, not any the result of functions performed using it. I believe the `doto` function is generally intended for side-effects. This is why you get the original string back.

Comment: are you sure its only meant to be used for side-effects. What would be otherwise a concise way to call multiple methods on an object in order? (something like `->>` and `->` macros

Comment: you can certainly use it for that. What i mean is that you would be performing mutations (with potential side-effects) on an existing java object in the purely functional sense

Comment: i am still a bit confused about its functionality. what would be an idiomatic situtation for example when one come across using `doto`, besides puting some print functions on its way to see the results of method calls?

Comment: @AmirTeymuri I use `doto` with mutable Java objects that need to be modifed after instanciation: `(doto (Widget.) (setVisible t) (setParent frame))` or for other side effects like printing.

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is the `..` threading macro ( https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/_.. ):

> Expands into a member access (.) of the first member on the first
>   argument, followed by the next member on the result, etc. For
>   instance:
>
> ```clj
> (.. System (getProperties) (get "os.name"))
> ```
>
> expands to:
>
> ```clj
> (. (. System (getProperties)) (get "os.name"))
> ```
>
> but is easier to write, read, and understand.

In your case:

```clj
(doto "clojure" .toUpperCase)
; => "clojure"

(.. "clojure" toUpperCase)
; => "CLOJURE"
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please also refer to the documentation?